# Pass Task<bool> with parameter and execute it

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I'm passing Task to Class library, where It needs to be executed, but with parameter value which can be obtained only within library Itself. I don't know how else to explain, maybe this example is more clear:

1.) Task that needs to be run from library:

```
 public async Task<bool> Login(string _password)
 {
    //...
 }
```

2.) Passing this Task to Class library (with string.Empty, because parameter will get It's real value in Class library)

```
 var _check = _myLibrary.ShowLogin(() => _myMethods.Login(string.Empty));
```

3.) Execute Task from Class Library, but with real parameter value.

```
 public partial class LoginWindow : Window
 {

   public ShowLogin(Func<Task<bool>> _checkpassword)
   {
     CheckPassword = _checkpassword;
   }

   public Func<Task<bool>> CheckPassword{ get; set; }

   public MessageBoxResult Result { get; set; }

   private async void Btn_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     var _check = await CheckPassword(Txt_password.Text); // ERROR HERE!

     if (!_check)
     {
       Result = MessageBoxResult.Cancel;
     }
     else
     {
       Result = MessageBoxResult.OK;
     }
           
     Close();
   }
}
```

Class library holds a collection of custom Windows that I'm showing in WPF. In this particular Window user has to enter password for Login. If password is correct, user can enter application, otherwise not. That is whole point.

**How can I call passed **Task** with parameter from library?**

EDIT: **Error is "'Delegate Func<Task>' does not take 1 arguments".**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use `Func<string, Task<bool>>`?

Comment: @emoacht, I'm working just on that. I'm not quite familliar with Func. How can I pass It (step 2) ? As seen in example It produces error : "Delegate Func<string, Task<bool>> does not take 0 arguments."

Comment: Just replace the Func as shown in Rekshino's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Func<Task<bool>>` is **`Task<bool> Login()`**, for you can pass a parameter you need to define `Func<string, Task<bool>>`. So all will look like:

```
var _check = _myLibrary.ShowLogin(_myMethods.Login);
var _checkAlternative = _myLibrary.ShowLogin((string pwd)=>_myMethods.Login(pwd));

public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
   public ShowLogin(Func<string, Task<bool>> _checkpassword)
   {
      CheckPassword = _checkpassword;
   }

   public Func<string, Task<bool>> CheckPassword{ get; set; }

   public MessageBoxResult Result { get; set; }

   private async void Btn_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var _check = await CheckPassword(Txt_password.Text); // NO ERROR HERE!
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you. But how can I pass Func<string,Task<bool>> in step 2 (my example)? Can you add this to example too ?

Comment: It's already in the answer. :D Even two possibilities.

Comment: thank you thank you ! I was so close all the time. Never stop learning in C# :)